# How to take advantage of the autocomplete with Komodo

Tags: php, keyboard-shortcuts, komodo, komodoedit, code-intelligence

I am a noob to Komodo and I'm trying to figure out how to use it to my best advantage. One thing keeps bugging me & there's probably a very simple answer.

As an example, when I type

```
if(isset($_GET['
```

Komodo will automatically fill in the rest of that line: `']))` which is great. Except that my cursor remains *before* that autocompleted part, so I have to move my hand to the arrows and manually navigate to the next line or the end of that line or whatever.

It seems like there should be a key combination to jump *past* the autocompleted brackets/parentheses/quotes so I can just continue on typing without moving over to the arrow keys.

**But I don't know what that is! Do you?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the combination of holding down the [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/defkeybind.html) ([<kbd>Alt</kbd> on OSX](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/osxkeybind.html)) while pressing the right arrow to jump to the end of the current statement.

Comment: Ah, such a simple answer -- but precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Caret stays there because Komodo understands you need to populate the string. Just hit <kbd>End</kbd> when done.